# How can I download GeoMesa on Azure Databricks?

Tags: azure-databricks, geomesa

I am interested in performing Big Data Geospatial analysis on Apache Spark. My data is stored in Azure data lake, and I am restricted to use Azure Databricks. Is there anyway to download Geomesa on Databrick? Moreover, I would like to use the python api; what should I do?

Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: Discussions like this might be easier to have on Gitter or one of the GeoMesa email lists.  See https://github.com/locationtech/geomesa#join-the-community for more info!

Answer (score 4):

You can install GeoMesa Library directly into your Databricks cluster.

**1)** Select the Libraries option then a new window will open.

[image]

**2)** Select the maven option and click on 'search packages' option
[image: next images]

**3)** Search the required library and select the library/jar version and choose the 'select' option.
Thats it.
[image: search the jar/library in maven repository]

After the installation of the library/jar, restart your cluster.
Now import the required classes in your Databricks notebook.
I hope it helps. Happy Coding..

Answer (score 1):

As a starting point, without knowing any more details, you should be able to use the GeoMesa [filesystem data store](https://www.geomesa.org/documentation/user/filesystem/index.html) against files stored in WASB.

Answer (score 1):

CCRi (backers of geomesa) has generated spark runtime friendly build. A shaded fat jar for GeoMesa (current version is 3.3.0) is available at the maven coordinates `org.locationtech.geomesa:geomesa-gt-spark-runtime_2.12:3.3.0` which for Databricks.​ ​S​ince it is shaded, users can add maven exclusions to get it to cleanly install which would be "`jline:*,org.geotools:*`" added in Databricks library UI without quotes​.

Answer (score 0):

Running GeoMesa within Databricks is not straightforward:

- GeoMesa’s artifacts are published on Maven Central, but require dependencies that are only available on third-party repositories, which is cumbersome given Databricks’ library import mechanism.
- GeoMesa conflicts with an older version of the scalalogging library present in the Databricks runtime (the infamous JAR Hell problem).

**Reference:** [Use GeoMesa in Databricks](https://cloudarchitected.com/2019/07/geospatial-analytics-in-databricks-with-python-and-geomesa/)

Hope this helps.